# fragment oncreateview is not being called when fragment activity starts

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I need to implement two tab options.
1)Top station 2)my station 
I used fragment activity with tab host.
I know actionbar should be used but according to psd I need to show tab option at bottom so I used tabhost as I do not know how to show actionbar at bottom of screen
It is done.
In my all fragment I am calling web service and parse json response and arrange response in lisview. 
I have written serve side communication code within oncreaview of fragment.
Problem I am facing is  when I swtich to my fragment activity from login activity fragment oncreateview is not being called so my listview doe s not appear.
But when I changed tab then its start appearing.
I put log and found that oncreatview of fragment is not beign called when activity is called.

Here is code of fragmentActivity:
Right Now I have used two fragment only.

```
    public class AwesomeActivityNew extends FragmentActivity implements
        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    private HashMap mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, TabInfo>();

    private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

    public class TabInfo {

        private String tag;

        private Class<?> clss;

        private Bundle args;

        private Fragment fragment;

        TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {

            this.tag = tag;

            this.clss = clazz;

            this.args = args;

        }

    }

    class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

        private final Context mContext;

        /**
         * 
         * @param context
         */

        public TabFactory(Context context) {

            mContext = context;

        }

        /**
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
         */

        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            View v = new View(mContext);

            return v;

        }

    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Step : Inflate layout

        setContentView(R.layout.maintab_new);

        // Step : Setup TabHost

        initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); // set
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // tab
                                                                                // as
                                                                                // per
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // saved
                                                                                // state

        }

    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.support.v.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab
                                                                // selected

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * Step : Setup TabHost
     */

    private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {

        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup();

        TabInfo tabInfo = null;

        AwesomeActivityNew.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Tab2 "),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", TopStation.class, args)));

        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

        AwesomeActivityNew.addTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
                .newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("My station", getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.star )),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", MyStation.class, args)));

        this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

        // Default to first tab

        this.onTabChanged("Tab");

        //

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param activity
     * 
     * @param tabHost
     * 
     * @param tabSpec
     * 
     * @param clss
     * 
     * @param args
     */

    private static void addTab(AwesomeActivityNew activity, TabHost tabHost,
            TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {

        // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec

        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));

        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably

        // from a previously saved state. If so, deactivate it, because our

        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.

        tabInfo.fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(tag);

        if (tabInfo.fragment != null && !tabInfo.fragment.isDetached()) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            ft.detach(tabInfo.fragment);

            ft.commit();

            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
     */

    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {

        TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);

        if (mLastTab != newTab) {

            FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            if (mLastTab != null) {

                if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {

                    ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);

                }

            }

            if (newTab != null) {

                if (newTab.fragment == null) {

                    newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,

                    newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);

                    ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag);

                } else {

                    ft.attach(newTab.fragment);

                }

            }

            mLastTab = newTab;

            ft.commit();

            this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

        }


    }
}
```

Here is code of Fragment:

```
    public class TopStation extends Fragment {

    boolean jsonloadflag = false;
//  int count = 0;
    int currentpage = 0;
    ListView ls;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    Downloader downloader;
    JSONLoader jsonloader;
    MyCustomadapter adp;
    int totalpages = 0;
    TextView page;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // HttpPost post = new
        // HttpPost("http://eluminoustechnologies.net/webapp/services/toptenstations.php");


    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!jsonloadflag) {
            jsonloader = new JSONLoader();
            jsonloader.execute(getActivity().getString(
                    R.string.web_root_service)
                    + getActivity().getString(+R.string.TOPTEN_STATION_URL));
        }
        Log.e("onattach top station called","true");
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // count = 0;
        //Log.e("oncreate view top station called","true");
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
        Log.e("inside top station oncrateview","true");
        currentpage = 0;
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_station, container, false);
        ls = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview_topstation);
        page = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        /*
         * View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_mystation, null);
         * ls.addFooterView(v1);
         */
        Button nextbtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnnext);
        Button previousbtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnprevious);

        new Downloader(currentpage).execute();
        nextbtn.setClickable(false);
        previousbtn.setClickable(false);
        nextbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (currentpage < totalpages) {
                    new Downloader(currentpage).execute();
                    currentpage += 1;
                    page.setText("Page " + currentpage);
                }
            }
        });
        previousbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (currentpage > 1) {
                    new Downloader(currentpage).execute();
                    currentpage -= 1;
                    page.setText("Page " + currentpage);
                }
            }
        });

        return v;

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

    }

    class MyCustomadapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> images;

        public MyCustomadapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ls,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> listbitmap) {

            this.data = ls;
            this.images = listbitmap;
            // this.data=imagename;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return images.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  Log.e("inside getview " + count, "true");
            View row;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null, false);
            // grid=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridrow, null);
            ImageView stationimg = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView stationname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            HashMap<String, String> map = data.get(position);
            HashMap<String, Bitmap> imagemap = images.get(position);
            stationname.setText(map.get("station_name"));
            // Log.e("map data for desc", map.get("description"));
            description.setText(map.get("description"));
            if (imagemap.get("station_picture") != null)
                stationimg.setImageBitmap(imagemap.get("station_picture"));
            // stationimg.setBackgroundResource(dataimg[position]);

            return (row);
        }
    }

    private class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        int cpage = 0;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> listbitmap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>>();

        public Downloader(int page) {
            this.cpage = page;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            adp = new MyCustomadapter(list, listbitmap);
            ls.setAdapter(adp);
            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.e("onPostExecute called", "true");
            Log.e("size of data list", "" + list.size());
            Log.e("size of data list", "" + listbitmap.size());
            dialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("do inbackground downloader of downloader called", "true");

            if (jsonloadflag) {
                for (int j = cpage * 4; j < cpage * 4 + 4
                        && j < jsonarray.length(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, Bitmap> imagemap = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
                    JSONObject jsonobj;
                    try {
                        jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(j);

                        String station_id = jsonobj.getString("station_id");
                        String station_name = jsonobj.getString("station_name");
                        String station_picture = jsonobj
                                .getString("station_picture");
                        String description = jsonobj.getString("description");
                        map.put("station_id", station_id);
                        map.put("station_name", station_name);
                        // map.put("station_picture", station_picture);
                        map.put("description", description);
                        String imageurl = getActivity().getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.web_root)
                                + getActivity().getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.station_image_path)
                                + station_picture.replace(" ", "%20");

                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(imageurl);

                            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                                    .openConnection();

                            conn.setDoInput(true);
                            conn.connect();
                            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                            Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                            if (bmImg != null)
                                imagemap.put("station_picture", bmImg);
                            else {
                                Drawable myDrawable = getResources()
                                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                                Bitmap defaultimg = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable)
                                        .getBitmap();
                                imagemap.put("station_picture", defaultimg);
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Log.e("station_id",station_id);
                        // Log.e("station_name", station_name);
                        // Log.e("station_picture",station_picture);
                        // Log.e("description", description);
                        // Log.e("counter is",""+count);
                        list.add(map);
                        listbitmap.add(imagemap);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            //  count += 5;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class JSONLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (jsonarray.length() > 0) {
                page.setText("Page " + 1);
                currentpage = 1;

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("do in background of json loader called", "true");
            if (!jsonloadflag) {
                jsonarray = parser.getJSONarrayFromUrl(params[0]);
                if (jsonarray.length() % 4 == 0)
                    totalpages = jsonarray.length() / 4;
                else
                    totalpages = jsonarray.length() / 4 + 1;
                // Log.e("url param", params[0]);
                // Log.e("server side json", jsonarray.toString());
                jsonloadflag = true;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    }
```

Please help that How can I show myfragment with serve side data loaded when my fragment Activity starts which contains tab host and fragment.

Answer (score 0):

could you explain bit more clearly on what the expected behavior is ? I looked through your code and the fragment oncreateview should be called when the fragment is activated, it won't be called when the activity starts. Also the data may take time to load from the asynctask and you may not see a result. Try with a shorter json data string from the server or try reading json from a preloaded asset/raw file.

Comment: Hi,When I clicked another tab and switch back to previous tab then data loads.Data does not load only when activity called.Means in starting blank but when I switch back data loading starts.